# Contact Form 7 Accept Only Certain Characters

Tags: regex

How can I set a text field of Contact Form 7 plugin to allow only certain characters?
I want this field to accept only Greek Characters which are considered as Special Characters.
Is there any way to add 24 characters for this?

Comment: How does `Contact Form 7` relate to regex?

Answer (score 1):

Contact form 7 version **4.5.1**. Its working for me.

```
//code to validate textbox
function custom_text_validation_filter($result, $tag) {  
      $type = $tag['type'];  
      $name = $tag['name'];
      //here textbox type name is 'subject'
      if($name == 'subject') { 
          $value = $_POST[$name];  
          if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~><>|=_+¬]/', $value)){
            $result->invalidate( $tag, "Invalid characters." );
          } 
      } 
      return $result;  
}
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text','custom_text_validation_filter', 10, 2); 
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_text_validation_filter', 10, 2); 

//code to validate textarea
function custom_textarea_validation_filter($result, $tag) {  
      $type = $tag['type'];  
      $name = $tag['name'];
      //here textarea type name is 'message'
      if($name == 'message') { 
          $value = $_POST[$name];  
          if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~><>|=_+¬]/', $value)){
            $result->invalidate( $tag, "Invalid characters." );
          } 
      }
      return $result;  
}
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_textarea','custom_textarea_validation_filter', 10, 2); 
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_textarea*', 'custom_textarea_validation_filter', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It most likely is possible, as others have shown it's possible to tailor it.

First register your callback methods:

```
//add fiter for text area validation
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_textarea', 'cf7_custom_textarea_validation', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_textarea*', 'cf7_custom_textarea_validation', 10, 2 );
```

And inside the callback, do your validation:

```
function cf7_custom_form_validation($result, $tag) 
{
    $type  = $tag['type'];
    $name  = $tag['name'];
    $value = $_POST[$name];

    ...

    if ($type == 'yourtype*' &&  !preg_match($your_regex, $value)) {
        $result['valid'] = false;
        $result['reason'][$name] = __('message for your regex not matching');
    }

    ...
```

See exemplare code here:

- https://github.com/m0xds/contact-form7-custom-validation/blob/master/cf7-custom-validation.php

Read an exemplary blogpost here:

- http://code-tricks.com/contact-form-7-custom-validation-in-wordpress/

Contact From 7 support is available here: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/contact-form-7

You find all Wordpress API functions documented in http://codex.wordpress.org/.

You find everything PHP related documented in http://php.net/docs